# How do I get table information in word2003 using POI？

Tags: java, apache-poi, word-2003

I try to get the width of each cell and then calculate their greatest common divisor to get the colspan of each cell, but how do I get the cell Rowspan? I tried using the method TableRow.getRowHeight(), but no matter what the table looks like, it's always going to be 0.
I am trying to use this method to convert to HTML, if you have a better way to convert complex tables to HTML, please help me, thanks!

Comment: Why using `Word 2003` in 2021? The binary file format of `Word 2003` is the most horrible of all the horrible binary `Microsoft Office` file formats. That's why `HWPF` is in scratchpad mode even in last version `Apache POI 5.1.0`. I doubt there is a really good solution using non commercial libraries. So if you stick on `Word 2003`, you probably need to buy a solution.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your advice, but this is because the company project needs to make a function to parse DOC and DOCX documents recently, so I have to use HWPF to parse doc. I have solved this problem through continuous attempts. Thanks again for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Integer getRowspan(TableCell cell, int rowNum, int colNum, Table table) {
    int rowSpan = 0;
    if (cell.isVerticallyMerged()) {
        if (cell.isFirstVerticallyMerged()) {
            for (int i = rowNum + 1; i < table.numRows(); i++) {
                TableCell tableCell = table.getRow(i).getCell(colNum);
                if (tableCell.isFirstVerticallyMerged() || !tableCell.isVerticallyMerged()) {
                    rowSpan = i - rowNum;
                    break;
                } else if (i == table.numRows() - 1) {
                    rowSpan = i - rowNum + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rowSpan;
}


public static Integer getColspan(TableCell cell, int rowNum, int colNum, Table table) {
    int colSpan = 0;
    if (cell.isMerged()) {
        if (cell.isFirstMerged()) {
            for (int i = colNum + 1; i < table.numRows(); i++) {
                TableCell tableCell = table.getRow(rowNum).getCell(i);
                if (tableCell.isFirstMerged() || !tableCell.isMerged()) {
                    colSpan = i - colNum;
                    break;
                } else if (i == table.numRows() - 1) {
                    colSpan = i - colNum + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return colSpan;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).